# adding new column to dataframe using formula

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe and the head() looks like this:

```
                  CEMETERY    SEX CONTEXT RaHD L RaHD R DIRECTIONAL ASYMMETRY
1 Medieval-St. Mary Graces FEMALE    7172   21.2   21.6                    NA
2 Medieval-St. Mary Graces   MALE    6225   23.9   25.2                    NA
3 Medieval-St. Mary Graces   MALE    9987   23.9   23.5                    NA
4 Medieval-St. Mary Graces   MALE   11475   22.4   22.3                    NA
5 Medieval-St. Mary Graces   MALE   12356   25.8   25.4                    NA
6 Medieval-St. Mary Graces   MALE   12525   22.4   22.3                    NA
```

(RaHD L and RaHD R are bone measurements).
I have just created the 'DIRECTIONAL ASYMMETRY' column by doing:

```
MRaHDTABLE["DIRECTIONAL ASYMMETRY"]=NA
```

and I now need to input data into that column. The formula for directional asymmetry is '%DA = (right - left) / (average of left and right) x 100'
so would be (RaHD R - RaHD L) / (average of RaHD R and RaHD L) x 100. I'm not sure how to input this into my table as I tried:

```
MRaHDTABLE$'DIRECTIONAL ASYMMETRY'=(MRaHDTABLE$`RaHD R`-
MRaHDTABLE$`RaHDL`)/mean(MRaHDTABLE$`RaHD L`,MRaHDTABLE$`RaHD R`)*100
```

but got the error:

```
Error in mean.default(MRaHDTABLE$`RaHD L`, MRaHDTABLE$`RaHD R`) : 
  'trim' must be numeric of length one
```

Comment: I'd recommend using valid row names in the future for ease of referencing columns, and clarity. `RaHD.L` and `RaHD_L` are both good alternatives.

Comment: Is the average for a particular row or is it for the whole data? for example the first value you need. is it   `(21.6 -21.2)/((21.6-21.2)/2)*100` or do you take the average of the whole column?

Comment: I need the average for each row (e.g. for the first row - (21.6+21.2)/2=21.4) - sorry didn't see the last part of your message - it would be that first equation you put

Comment: Define a little function `DA <- function(x, y) {(x-y)/mean(x,y)*100}`, and then `mapply(DA, x= MRaHDTABLE$'RaHD L', y= MRaHDTABLE$'RaHD R')`

Comment: @AislingMurray No prob, moving my comment to an actual answer

Comment: you can also do `apply(data[c("RaHD L", "RaHD R")],1,function(x) diff(x)/mean(x)*100)`

Comment: one more question (sorry!) - I have added data from post-medieval cemeteries to my data frame and now want to rename the vectors in the CEMETERY column (so it will simply be 'Medieval' and 'Postmedieval' rather than give the entire cemetery name

Comment: @AislingMurray, please post this as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `mean` function incorrectly in your formula. If you look at the documentation (`?mean`), the function takes three arguments: a numeric vector (x), the fraction of values to be trimmed (trim), and how to treat missing values (na.rm). Therefore, in your specification `` mean(MRaHDTABLE$`RaHD L`,MRaHDTABLE$`RaHD R`) ``, the first term is interpreted as the input vector (x),and the second term is interpreted as the the trim parameter.

Try replace

```
mean(MRaHDTABLE$`RaHD L`,MRaHDTABLE$`RaHD R`)
```

With

```
rowMeans(name_of_df[ , c(4,5)])
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP has asked to implement the formula

> (RaHD R - RaHD L) / (average of RaHD R and RaHD L) x 100

The answers posted so far are trying to make the `mean()` function work row-wise just to compute the average of two numbers which simply is

> average of RaHD R and RaHD L = (RaHD R + RaHD L) / 2

So, the answer could be as simple as:

```
MRaHDTABLE["DIRECTIONAL.ASYMMETRY"] <- 
  with(MRaHDTABLE, 200 * (RaHD.R - RaHD.L) / (RaHD.R + RaHD.L))
MRaHDTABLE
```

> ```
>   i           X2    CEMETERY    SEX CONTEXT RaHD.L RaHD.R DIRECTIONAL.ASYMMETRY
> 1 1 Medieval-St. Mary Graces FEMALE    7172   21.2   21.6             1.8691589
> 2 2 Medieval-St. Mary Graces   MALE    6225   23.9   25.2             5.2953157
> 3 3 Medieval-St. Mary Graces   MALE    9987   23.9   23.5            -1.6877637
> 4 4 Medieval-St. Mary Graces   MALE   11475   22.4   22.3            -0.4474273
> 5 5 Medieval-St. Mary Graces   MALE   12356   25.8   25.4            -1.5625000
> 6 6 Medieval-St. Mary Graces   MALE   12525   22.4   22.3            -0.4474273
> ```

**Note** The data look differently to OP's posted data. This is due to OP's failure to provide sample data in a *reproducible* way, i.e., by posting the result of `dput(MRaHDTABLE)`. So, I tried to reproduce the data with a less effort as possible.

The `with()` function is used to save typing.

#### Data

```
MRaHDTABLE <- data.frame(readr::read_table(
 "  i                 CEMETERY    SEX CONTEXT RaHD.L RaHD.R DIRECTIONAL.ASYMMETRY
  1 Medieval-St. Mary Graces FEMALE    7172   21.2   21.6                    NA
  2 Medieval-St. Mary Graces   MALE    6225   23.9   25.2                    NA
  3 Medieval-St. Mary Graces   MALE    9987   23.9   23.5                    NA
  4 Medieval-St. Mary Graces   MALE   11475   22.4   22.3                    NA
  5 Medieval-St. Mary Graces   MALE   12356   25.8   25.4                    NA
  6 Medieval-St. Mary Graces   MALE   12525   22.4   22.3                    NA"
))
```